# curl gives an ERROR on Mac OS

Tags: macos, curl, macos-sierra

when running curl via Terminal, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I installed the latest version of Xcode and even "brew install curl" but neither helped. any ideas what is going on??

(OS Sierra)

Comment: What is the output of `which curl`? The location showing looks similar to MacPorts.

Comment: /opt/local/bin/curl

Comment: What is the output of `curl --version`?

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Comment: The location showing definitely is not the native Apple version ( it's in `/usr/bin`). I think you've got the MacPorts version installed (`port installed`) should return the packages installed. You can either uninstall it or reinstall it and it might fix the issue. (`sudo port uninstall/install curl`)

Comment: amazing, it worked... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the version of `curl` installed is incomplete. It appears that it's one installed from `MacPorts`, since `/opt/local/bin/curl` is the normal location of where it installs.

The native Apple version is in `/usr/bin`.

You can either uninstall or reinstall the MacPorts version:

```
sudo port install curl
```

or to uninstall

```
sudo port uninstall curl
```

↳ [MacPorts Common Tasks](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.common-tasks.html)